# Localization with editable messages at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization

for several reasons, in need to localize my application giving the possibility to the final customer to modify the displayed messages (labels, content of buttons, popup messages).
This has to be done by simply editing the XAML(resource dictionary) file which contains the messages of the application: is it possible??
I mean, is possible to compile the application keeping outside the .exe pack the merged dictionaries??

Thank you,

L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, that is the solution i used for my application. Just set the properties of the .xaml resource dictionnary files as Content / Copy Always. Then in your code you can load the resources with :

```
MyXmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(MyResourceFileName)
MyResourceDictionary = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(MyXmlReader)
```

But beware that it is easy to have broken tags, depending on your Customer's technical knowledge. So you should try/catch code above, and provide error message (with line number).
Maybe it wouldn't be too hard to provide a small tool that allows safer edit of the dictionnary (just a ListView Full of TextBlock/TextBox :=) ).

Comment: Thank you!... And I agree with you, but user requirements are user requirements!! :)